# Join query with user provided data-T-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requriment where user will provide many Ids(in Hundres/thousands) in a Text area in vb.net app, I need to use these IDs in T-Sql(Sql Server) to get the data. I dont want to save these Ids in any database table. Just want to pass using a paramater (type of varchar(max)) and use in the procedure.

actually, only read access is permitted for the vb application users.It is Sql-2005 database.Id field is atleaset 12 to 15 characters length.The user will copy/paste data from other source may be CSV or Excel file.

any idea how can i achive this.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008+ look at table valued parameters.

Comment: If you on Sql 2008 or later, I would recommend using [Table Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) - this will allow you to build up a set of rows containing the Ids, which you can then join on in your `PROC`, without the pain of validating against Sql Injection attacks, escaping quotes, etc. In prior versions, you can also abuse the Xml data type in similar fashion.

Comment: Are you sure about the requirement? Did the client really say 'I want to enrage my users until they go on strike'? Are users REALLY going to type the values one by one? Perhaps the selections are already stored somewhere, eg a table or CSV file that you can process on the server, (eg with SSIS). Passing the values as text will be very slow, expose you to sql injection attacks and generate suboptimal results, when it works. If you have that many IDs, even TVPs may not be enough and you will have to use tables.

Comment: actually, only read access is permitted for the vb application users.It is Sql-2005 database.Id field is atleaset 12 to 15 characters length.The user will copy/paste data from other source may be CSV or Excel file.

Comment: Don't. Import the file to a table in the server eg using SSIS and then do a JOIN. Or explain to the customer they will have to wait as you execute the queries in batches, in a very slow way

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Table Valued Parameters, as suggested elsewhere, and you don't want to store the ID's in a temporary table, you can do the following.

Assuming your ID's are integer values, that are separated by commas, in the parameter string, you can use the LIKE operator in your SQL-statement's WHERE filter:

Say you have a parameter, `@IDs` of type varchar(max). You want to get only those records from MyTable where the ID-column contains a value that has been typed into the @IDs-parameter. Then your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ',' + @IDs + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(ID AS varchar) + ',%'
```

Notice how I prepend and append an extra comma to the @IDs parameter. This is to ensure that the LIKE operator will still work as expected for the first and last ID in the string. Make sure to take the nescessary precautions against SQL injection, for example by validating that users are only allowed to input integer digits and commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CHARINDEX`:

```
DECLARE @selectedIDs varchar(max) = '1,2,3'
Set @selectedIDs = ',' + @selectedIds + ',' --string should always start and end with ','

SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(IDColumn as VARCHAR(10)) + ',', @selectedIds) > 0
```